# php receive two images come from HttpClient

Tags: php

client-side i used httpmime-4.2 jar to send two images and string to php:my code:

```
private void postFile() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ConstValue.SEARCH_BY_PICTER);

    File file = new File(currentPath);

    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();


    try {
        mpEntity.addPart("fileToUpload", cbFile);
        mpEntity.addPart("sys", new StringBody("android"));
        mpEntity.addPart("ver", new StringBody(ConstValue.VERSION_NAME));
        mpEntity.addPart("cid", new StringBody(cid));
        mpEntity.addPart("page", new StringBody("1"));
        mpEntity.addPart("offset", new StringBody("80"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
        errorCheck=73;
    }

    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //Log.i("wu",""+55555);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        errorCheck=74;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
         //Log.d("log", "aaaaa："+e1.getMessage());
    }

    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();




    if (resEntity != null) {
        try {
            final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);



            if (!response_str.contains("@@@@")) {

                ResContent res=NetUtil.parseResponse(response_str);
                switch(Integer.valueOf(res.code)){
                case 0:
                    errorCheck=0;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    errorCheck=2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    errorCheck=3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    errorCheck=4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    errorCheck=5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    errorCheck=6;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ConstValue.goodByPiclist = GoodXMLUtil.parseResponse(response_str);
                    if(ConstValue.goodByPiclist.size()<1)
                    {                           
                        errorCheck=70;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } else {

                errorCheck=71;
            }

            // Log.d("log", response_str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MyDebug.d(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }else{
        errorCheck=72;
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

 }
```

but i donot know php server how to get  the images,can you give some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the `httpmime-4.2` package you are using to do this, but two things that immediately strike me about your code are:

1. Where does the undeclared variable `currentPath` come from? Surely this should either be an argument of your method or `this.currentPath`.
2. You never actually connect the `httpclient` and `httppost` objects, so I doubt this request will work how you want it to, if at all.

Aside from these things, any files uploaded via POST are available to PHP in the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array, [the usage of which is well documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

**EDIT**

Assuming the request works as it should (I still have my doubts) this is some sample code of how the data could accessed in PHP:

```
<?php

  echo "Hello! ".count($_POST)." POST parameters were received, and ".count($_FILES)." files were received.<br />\n";

  foreach ($_FILES as $postField => $fileData) {
    echo "The file {$fileData['name']} ({$fileData['type']}, {$fileData['size']} bytes) was received in the POST field $postField<br />\n";
    if ($fileData['name']['error']) {
      echo "The upload failed with error code {$fileData['name']['error']}<br />\n";
      continue;
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($fileData['tmp_name'],"/path/to/store/uploads/{$fileData['name']}")) {
      echo "File saved to disk successfully<br />\n";
    } else {
      echo "Could not save file to disk!<br />\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: currentPath is a global variable, is the image save path in other method.

Comment: why said my  request  not work ,my methods works run well,i test it,my question is sometimes one phone not get data,but when some times it ca run very well

Comment: thank you ,my code work very well, i donot know my officemate how to write the php,i can upload my images,but i have two phone,sometime only one can upload